# Ошибка при слитии проекта на GitHub error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, git-push, git-bash

вчера решил залить в репозиторий, все прошло успешной, но сегодня git выдает ошибку, и я не могу понять в чем ошибка.
Вчера сливал проект данным способом:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/Sholokhov99/Web.git
git push -u origin master
```

Но сегодня решил добавить в данный репозиторий новую директиву данным способом:

```
git init
git add SnakeJSGame
git commit -m 'commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/Sholokhov99/Web.git
git push -u origin master
```

Но в ответ получил данную ошибку

```
 To https://github.com/Sholokhov99/Web.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Sholokhov99/Web.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Когда в GH создаётся репозиторий, он не пустой (не знаю, чем они там думали), поэтому **первый** раз надо делать `git push -u --force origin master`. Полно таких вопросов здесь. Модераторам на заметку, дубликат на 99.9%.

Comment: Если же рчень хочется сохранить то, что уже есть на GH, то тогда делаем `git pull --rebase origin master; git push`. Тоже миллион вопросов-ответов на эту тему.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084169/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-git-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ты в гитхабе чото наделал.

пишешь `git pull` и все работает!

Comment: Ответ не раскрывает, в чём проблема человека. Более того, судя по всему, Вы не знаете, как работает pull! Таким образом можно перетереть уже существующие правки.

Comment: @hedgehogues Охх... жаль ругаться нельзя

Comment: @hedgehogues пулом правки перетереть?

Comment: @hedgehogues ля, только увидел что вы написали "Вы НЕ знаете...". Я знаю, git pull делает изменения, которые были в github

Comment: А ещё git pull == fit fetch + git merge. И здесь может быть проблема. Конфликты и бла-бла-бла